# Mac OS X Virtual Box Windows XP F Keys

Tags: macos, mac, virtualbox

A general work day for me consists of 50% mac, 50% windows virtual box usage on the mac.  When I use the mac side of things, I love how the F keys interact, when I am on windows, I rely heavily on the F keys which forces me to have to use the FN key.  Is their any option or way to force my virtual box instance of windows into accepting the f keys by default?

Comment: This question (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13455/function-keystrokes-ate-by-host-when-running-win7-in-a-virtualbox) can help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no easy(ish) way to make something receive the function keys on a Mac. Probably involving patching the system itself, which would be a bad idea.

---

Your F keys have two modes:

- Regular F-key behavior (this is what you want in Windows)
- Special function keys (brightness, volume, etc.; this is what you want on your Mac?)

You switch between then by pressing or releasing `Fn`. But you can toggle which one's are received when not pressing Fn:

[image]

---

You can create a simple AppleScript or Automator workflow that let's you toggle the `Fn` key setting, I described that [in this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/243682/can-you-toggle-function-keys-on-off-with-a-keyboard-shortcut-on-osx/243702#243702).

---

If you want to use regular F-keys on both Windows and Mac and want to disable Expose, Spaces, Dashboard for a while, write a script that uses `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` or `defaults` to modify your `~/Libary/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` file as described on [this other web site by the user fracai](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=114785):

```
# All Windows - F9
32 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 101, 0 ); type = standard; }; }; 

# Application Windows - F10
33 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 109, 0 ); type = standard; }; }; 

# All Windows (Slow) - F9
34 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 101, 131072 ); type = standard; }; }; 

# Application Windows (Slow) - F10
35 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 109, 131072 ); type = standard; }; }; 

# Desktop - F11
36 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 103, 0 ); type = standard; }; }; 

# Desktop (Slow) - F11
37 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 103, 131072 ); type = standard; }; }; 

# Dashboard - F12
62 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 111, 0 ); type = standard; }; }; 

# Dashboard (Slow) - F12
63 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 111, 131072 ); type = standard; }; }; 

# Activate Spaces - F8
75 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 100, 0 ); type = standard; }; }; 

# Activate Spaces (Slow) - Shift, F8
76 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 100, 131072 ); type = standard; }; };
```