# How to swap the effect of fn-key for osx?

Tags: macos, macbook, keyboard-layout, fn-key

I want to swap the effect of fn-key for some of the F1-F12 keys. How can I achieve this on osx (10.6) on a macbook? Ideally I should be able to toggle the effect for individual keys, but a solution toggling all will also do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/).

---

Toggle all in *System Preferences*:

[image]

Use [this script](https://superuser.com/questions/243682/can-you-toggle-function-keys-on-off-with-a-keyboard-shortcut-on-osx/243702#243702) to toggle using keyboard shortcut or otherwise semi-automated.